# How to round corners of plane?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

[image]

How can I cut an arc into a square plane? The gif above shows what I want to do, but, in another software.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

No need to subdivide the whole plane, no need to add vertex groups or modifiers!

**All you need is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>** and middle mouse button scrolling on vertex or vertices:

[image]

Comment: much thanks its to shortcut i know to bevel but this bevel is awesome

Comment: Thats one very useful hidden feature, thanks!

Comment: Any way to do this with a trackpad?

Comment: @rraallvv Not interactively. You have to confirm the operator then go into operator options (bottom of Tools panel) and set the parameters of that bevel.

Answer (score 23):

You can achieve this with the *Bevel* modifier.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode and select the corners you want to curve. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd> or click *Mesh -> Vertices -> Vertex Groups -> Assign to New Group* to assign them to a new vertex group.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to object mode and add a *Bevel* modifier.
Enable *Only Vertices* set *Limit Method* to *Vertex Group* and select the vertex group you just created (by default it will be named Group). Adjust *Segments* and *Width* to meet your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could subdivide a plane twice, then add a subsurf modifier at level 2. 
To sharpen the edge on one side and remove the rounded form, add an edge loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Subsurf will not add circular arc. It adds a spline arc which is C2 smooth opposed to circular arc which is not.

Comment: This method is not very performance efficient. It adds way too many unnecessary polygons. Bevel is much better.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with this also (a silly one) - if you have scaled your object unequally you will not get a circular bevel, but rather an elliptical one. This makes sense, and is how it should work. Just object menu --> apply --> scale before you bevel to fix it.

Comment: You saved my day … +1