# How to build a rectangle with convex edges and rounded corners?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to build this shape. what is the more efficient way to make these blue rounded polygons? I would like to create rectangles with convex edges and so rounded corners.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this: if the exact shape is important, trace the bitmap to svg, then import the svg and import it to Blender, convert to mesh, clean the mesh... done! Here it goes:

Open Inkscape, paste the png and trace it like this:

[image]

you need to clean the traced paths, delete whatever is not your desired shapes...

then delete the bitmap, save the svg and import it in Blender: scale the imported curve enough (I did 50x), and put "geometry to the center" using the toolbox function (left panel).

[image]

then, convert curve to mesh, and change material color if you wish:

[image]

[image]

Then, convert all mesh triangles (many) to simple ngons, using limited dissolve:

[image]

there you are! Of course you have many vertices...

[image]

Of course you could also just keep the vector/curves....

Comment: I was also wondering how to simply build a rectangle with convex edges . I tried to bevel the edges but doesn't work (CTRL+B).

Comment: to do that, you could use subdiv modifier or bevel on a (at least slightly) subdivided plane...

Comment: eg: see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63815/919