# Bevel modifier not working on one object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, objects

I have been trying to round the corners of an object. I used the suggested bevel modifier as per ([How to round corners of plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63794/how-to-round-corners-of-plane)). However it did not work for me so I tested it in a new file on a similar object and it worked just fine. Can anyone tell me why it would not work on the appended object in the linked file?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifiers don't work properly when an object is scaled.

Your object has scale 0.005.

After you Apply scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, the bevel will start to work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ever so much. That did the trick. Oh the woes of learning blender, just when you think you are making progress.......... :)