# Bevel just a face

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

As I was watching a tutorial from [Daniel Lepik](https://lepikdaniel.com) on his Instagram, I noticed a pretty nice trick where he seems to bevel a face after Inset/Extruding inwards, which enables him to make a circular or rounded hole or object inside a square face:

[image]

[image]

I have redrawn the screenshots here to make it more legible:

[image]

It seems like a simple and efficient solution to create round meshes inside faces while limiting the number of polygons and respecting good topology. Also, it doesn't require a modifier which would impact the whole mesh.

However, in **Blender**, I cannot find any options for **Beveling** **Inset** or **Extruded** faces. I looked in the tool shelf while **Extruding** / **Insetting**, nothing. I tried the **Bevel** shortcut when the face was selected, nothing. **Google**, nothing.

### Can this be done in Blender?

*Edit: Following Legoman's answer, I was able to subdivide in a way close to what I am trying to do, but still not sure it is the best way:*

Technique 1 <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> then to round the shape <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

Technique 2 (sorry about the weird moiré effect at the beginning)

[image]

Comment: I don't really get those descriptions while screenshots are quite lowres, but it looks like you're searching for beveling vertices (Ctrl+Shift+B or option in the modifier), e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63794/how-to-round-corners-of-plane. Note though that multiple edges from one vertex as in the first picture isn't really good topology

Comment: I think if you select a single vertex loop and bevel, you will get the effect like Mr Zak is talking about....

Comment: Apologies for the low-resolution - instagram TV is only accessible on the instagram app, not the desktop version. [You might be able to find this on Lepik's instagram on the app](https://www.instagram.com/lepikdaniel/?hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

Try selecting your face, tapping ctrl+B, and then press V. This should provide the desired effect. (You may need to delete the center face first.) Afterwards, just snap the four undesired vertices to the corner of the cube and remove doubles.

Comment: I incorporated elements of your answer into an edit of the question, I am close to marking as valid answer if you can develop a bit! Thanks

Comment: Developed. I think this is what you were going for (if not in quite as few steps).

Answer (score 1):

See the Loop Tools Addon located in the tools.
Circle is a feature.
So if you have plane with grid vertices cut out, you can easily arrange the vertices to a circle.

[image]

Blender Bevel Modifier Can be Selective

It can operate on vertex groups

Non destructive and you can change segments at anytime.

[image]
The image above shows the use of two different vertex groups. The color options was used.

- We use two bevel modifiers to show beveling can be selective and composed.
- Create two vertex groups.
- Each one uses a different vertex group as indicated by the gold arrows.
- There are so many options and ways to do this with the modifier.
- There is an option Vertex Group
- The above image was a cube and is beveled.

Comment: It seems that you are creating additional geometry on every single face of your model in image 1, also, it seems like it would be difficult to easily change the radius of the cylinder coming out of the tube, because of said additional geometry. In your second picture, your middle shape still looks like a square coming out of a square

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one very easy way to achieve the beveled corners, and perfect circle is only one step further.

To get the nicely beveled corners, simply extrude the shape that you want to bevel the corners of, then bevel the edges that connect to the vertices you want to bevel. Finally, delete the extruded vertices and you should be left with the desired result.

To get a perfect circle, you can use the *Circle* tool in the loop tools addon as MicroMachine mentioned, or use the *To Sphere* operator (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). The loop tools command will give you a perfect circle with evenly spaced vertices, but can rotate the circle a bit that you may want to correct later. The *To Sphere* operator will not rotate the circle, but will not evenly distribute the vertices, meaning you need a roughly even distribution of vertices to get a decent result.

Probably a bit confusing when I explain it with words, so here's a gif to clear things up. I used the Loop Tools Circle tool in this example, and just roughly rotated the circle to where it should be. There may be a way to figure out the exact number of degrees it gets offset, but that I don't know.

[image]