# round corners inverted of a plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, faces

this is a face in my object.

[image]

I initially planned to have it this form and let the white part be transparent. However, because of a few reasons I now want to cut the white part from the plane. How would I do this?

The nearest I found is this solution:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63815

This comes close to what I want to do, but I need the corner the other way round

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to manually cut it out. In edit mode, press K to bring up the knife tool. Cut along where you want and press Enter when you're done. You can then delete the face you want.

To get straight lines, press C while in Knife mode for constrained angles.

If you want a cleaner mesh with only quads, use the knife tool again and connect the vertices from where you cut to the edge of the plane. Repeat this with each vertex to create quads.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ctrl+Shift+B will bevel vertices. Use this, and then roll the mouse wheel to get a smoother curve.

Then, if you notice in the bottom option bar, there is something called "Profile Control" on the P key.

Enabling this will allow you to switch the direction in which the bevel is pointing by moving the mouse. This will allow you to achieve the "inverted" curve you have there all in one operation, and then it should be very easy to adjust it as needed to remove the white part of the plane.